# Changing UITextView after a UIButton has been pressed

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm trying to change a `UITextView` after a `UIButton` has been pressed, for example my text view says "bananas" and when a button is press the same text view must change to "are delicious."

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up an outlet to your UITextField (calling it textField in this example) and an Action to your UIButton.

Your action would look something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.textField setText:@"are delicious"];
}
```